# How to power up cores 2 and 3 on XU7

Tags: arm64, boot, xilinx, multicore

In Vitis 2022.2, when creating multiple applications to run on the 4 Cortex A53 cores of the Xilinx XU7 MPSoC, I get the message *"cannot reset Cortex-A53 #2. Core is powered down"* when starting a debug session.  This is also the case for core #3.  I could not figure out where to enable or power up the additional cores.  Also, for the RPU core #1, I get this message *"Processor in Lock Step Mode"*.  What did I miss?